# Saving a qlistwidget after closing application

Tags: qt, profile, notepad, qlistwidget

I have a program that allows for a user to create a profile that saves values using qsettings, the user accesses their profile by clicking on the name in a qlistwidget. I am trying to save the names of the profiles by using a text file but I am having trouble saving more than one profile name at a time. thank you! here is the code:

for saving a profilename to the text document

```
void Profile::writeProfilenames()
{
    QString profilename = ui->lineEdit_profilename->text();
    profilename = profilename.simplified();
    QFile pfile("profilenames.txt");
    if (!pfile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        return;
    }

    QTextStream out(&pfile);
    out << profilename;
    pfile.flush();
    pfile.close();

}
```

for retrieving the profile names from the document

```
void Profile::readProfilenames()
{
    QFile pfile("profilenames.txt");
    if (!pfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly |
                       QIODevice::Text))
   {
        return;
   }

    QString proname = pfile.readLine();
    QListWidgetItem *itm = new QListWidgetItem;
    itm->setText(proname);
    ui->listWidget_profiles->insertItem(0,itm);
}
```

P.S. if you know of a better way to do this then feel free to share! (with example please)

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite see why you're saving the list of names in a text file, while the settings themselves are saved in a platform-specific fashion using `QSettings`.

The code you show has several problems:

1. Presumably you don't want to "write" the name to the file, overwriting the existing contents at the beginning, but specifically to *append* to the file. You also must specify a writable path to the file, so far you're using the current working directory that is: variable, not under your control, and not necessarily writable. Your code also doesn't handle repeated names.
2. `QFile` is a proper C++ class, and embodies the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) principles. You don't have to do *anything* to flush and close the file. The compiler takes care of generating the proper code for you. That's why you're using C++ and not C, after all. Yes, your code compiles, but it reads like C, and such verbosity is unnecessary and counterproductive.
3. You're only retrieving *one* name from the file. You want to retrieve all of them.

I'd say that you should dispense with the file access, set up your application's identification, a crucial prerequisite to using `QSettings`, and, finally, use them:

```
struct Profile {
  QString name;
  int age;
}

void saveProfiles(const QList<Profile> & profiles)
{
  QSettings s;
  s.beginWriteArray("profiles");
  for (int i = 0; i < profiles.size(); ++i) {
    s.setArrayIndex(i);
    const Profile & p = profiles.at(i);
    s.setValue("name", p.name);
    s.setValue("age", p.age);
  }
  s.endArray(); //optional
}

QList<Profile> loadProfiles()
{
  QList<Profile> profiles;
  QSettings s;
  int size = s.beginReadArray("profiles");
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    s.setArrayIndex(i);
    Profile p;
    p.name = s.value("name").toString();
    p.age = s.value("age").toInt();
    profiles << p;
  }
  s.endArray(); // optional
  return profiles;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  app.setOrganizationName("fluxD613"); // ideally use setOrganizationDomain instead
  app.setApplicationName("fluxer");
  ...
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I implement qsettings in another forum/window and the profilename is just "keyword" that is passed over to the other forum to tell what settings to use. will this code still work? also i am getting the following errors that i am having trouble resolve: in `saveProfilenames` the compiler says that there is an expected initializer before '&' tokenbefore and that `p` was not declared in this scope. if I take at the address operator, it compiles just fine.If I understand the code correctly, this creates a QList of profilenames that i can then add to the listwidget? thanks for the help

Comment: @fluxD613 It was a reference, it's fixed.

Comment: where do the actual names of the profiles that the user makes go? for example the ui-> lineedit->text()

Comment: @fluxD613 It's up to you. You can put them in `Profile.name`, or `Profile.profileName` or whatever. I don't know what you want to do, you have to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more research and trial and error I came up with the following code that does the trick:
this function is implemented when I close the profiles dialog window and return to the main window using `QCloseEvent`.

```
 void Profile::writeProfilenames()
{
QFile pfile("profilenames.txt");
if (!pfile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    return;
}

for(int row = 0; row < ui->listWidget_profiles->count(); row++)
{
    QListWidgetItem *item = ui->listWidget_profiles->item(row);
    QTextStream out(&pfile);
    out << item->text().simplified() << "\n";
}

pfile.close();

}
```

reading the list of profilenames is implemented when I open the dialog window just under `ui->setup(this)`.

```
void Profile::readProfilenames()
{

QFile pfile("profilenames.txt");
if (!pfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly |
                       QIODevice::Text))
   {
    return;
   }
QTextStream in(&pfile);
while (!in.atEnd())
{
    QString line = in.readLine();
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem;
    item->setText(line);
    ui->listWidget_profiles->addItem(item);
}

pfile.close();

}
```

I am now working on making sure the user does not enter a profilename that already exists and deleting a profilename from the QListWidget.